# Accessing array values in twig loop

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I cannot access to cars in TWIG but code below works fine in controller itself. I'm getting error like this when trying to access cars in Twig:

```
Method "model" for object "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" does not exist in
```

**None of these DOESN'T WORK in TWIG loop below:**

```
{{ car.model }}
{{ cars.model }}
{{ brand.car.model }}
{{ brand.cars.model }}
{{ brand.car.car.model }}
{{ brand.car.cars.model }}
{{ brand.cars.car.model }}
{{ brand.cars.cars.model }}
```

**This work fine TWIG file:**

```
{% for brand in result %}
   {{ brand.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

**CONTROLLER (Works fine):**

```
    foreach ($result as $brand)
    {
        echo $brand->getName() . ':';

        foreach ($brand->getCars() as $car)
        {
            echo $car->getModel() . ',';
        }

        echo '<br />';
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
bmw:3.16,3.18,
mercedes:amg,
```

**QUERY IN REPOSITORY:**

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT car, brand
                            FROM CarBrandBundle:Brands brand
                            JOIN brand.cars car
                            ORDER BY
                                brand.name ASC,
                                car.model ASC');
```

Comment: did you add `$this->BRANDS_OR_CARS = new ArrayCollection()` in constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cars is an array so you need to loop through them like..

```
{% for car in brand.cars %}
    {{ car.model }}
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively you could access it like `{{ brans.cars[0].model }}` but then you would have to know how many cars there are beforehand.

Comment: Not actualy an array but a `PersistentCollection`

Comment: To be honest it was my last choice but seems like only choice so I'll have to accept it. Thanks.